# Proving a function in $ \mathbb{R}^2$ is convex

Tags: convexity-inequality

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=\ln(e^{5x}+e^{2y})$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

According to what I've seen (and taught by my teachers), a function $f$ is convex if it satisfies

$(\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2, 0\leq t\leq 1)$

$f(t\cdot x+(1-t)\cdot y)\leq t\cdot f(x) +(1-t)\cdot f(y)$

I'm trying to prove the given function is convex by simply choosing $a=(x_1,y_1),b=(x_2,y_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and applying to the lefthand side of the inequality, yet after playing around with the equation, I cannot seem to find a way to prove the required inequality.

Any ideas/path of thoughts would be of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be a convex function, a sufficient condition for a $f \in C^2(\mathbb R^2)$ is that the Hessian matrix of $f$ be positive **semidefinite** for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.
Now
$$
H(x,y) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\frac{{25e^{5x + 2y} }}{{\left( {e^{5x}  + e^{2y} } \right)^2 }}} & { - \frac{{10e^{5x + 2y} }}{{\left( {e^{5x}  + e^{2y} } \right)^2 }}}  \\
   { - \frac{{10e^{5x + 2y} }}{{\left( {e^{5x}  + e^{2y} } \right)^2 }}} & {\frac{{4e^{5x + 2y} }}{{\left( {e^{5x}  + e^{2y} } \right)^2 }}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$
and its eigenvalues are
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \lambda _1  = \frac{{29e^{5x + 2y} }}{{\left( {e^{5x}  + e^{2y} } \right)^2 }} > 0\,\,\,\,\forall \left( {x,y} \right) \in \mathbb R^2 \\ 
 \lambda _2  = 0 \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
This is how to say that $H(x,y)$ is positive semidefinite, whence the thesis.

Comment: If the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix at some $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are non-negative ($\geq 0$) than can I claim that $f$ is convex at that $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, what you claim is true.

Answer (score 0):

Another method with less computations, but only for this type of function.

Observe that $f(x,y) = 5x + \ln(1+e^{2y-5x})$. Since the functions $(x,y) \mapsto 5x$ and $(x,y) \mapsto 2y-5x$ are affine (and even linear), the convexity of $f$ follows from the convexity of the function $g : z \mapsto \ln(1+e^z)$, which follows from the fact that
$$g'(z) = \frac{e^z}{1+e^z} = \frac{1}{e^{-z}+1}$$
is an increasing function of $z$.